# Horizontally aligning inner `divs`

Tags: html, css

I am looking to horizontally (and preferably vertically) align three inner `divs`. Applying `margin: 0 auto;` to class `vbox` should do the trick but as in the following minimal code, it isn't affecting the alignment at all. How can i accomplish this aligning?

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id='site'>
    <div class='main'>
      <div class='vbox'>
        <div id='inner1'>inner1</div>
        <div id='inner2'>inner2</div>
        <div id='inner3'>inner3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#site {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#main {}

.vbox {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The result can be seen in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ko9sqnzo/2/) fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the width for vbox:

```
.vbox {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;/*apply as your own*/
}
```

100% wide element is centered horizontally but you see no alignment for text. For this you should apply `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id='site'>
    <div class='main'>
      <div class='vbox'>
        <div class='inner'>inner1</div>
        <div class='inner'>inner2</div>
        <div class='inner'>inner3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
 #main {
  width: 100%;
}

.vbox {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give `display: table;` to `.vbox` will make it horizontal center.

```
.vbox {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ko9sqnzo/3/)**

Another solution is `display: flex;`

```
.main {
    display: flex;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ko9sqnzo/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: inline-block for your inner divs:

```
.vbox {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0; /* white spaces fix */
}

.vbox > div {
  font-size: 1rem; /* white spaces fix */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ko9sqnzo/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
#site {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#main {
  Width:100%;
}

.vbox {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:0;
}
.vbox div{
  width:32%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

The important bit is that the default behavior of a div is to take up the full width of its parent. To change this you give it the display mode inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to align all 3 divs vertically by using:

```
#site {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#main {}

.vbox {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.vbox div{
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

If you have more divs or less, just update the width accordingly.